# Import multiple protobuf files with common message names in a single proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-go

I have several protobuf files that share some message names and for this reason I cannot have all the generated go files in one folder as I run into issues like "..re-declared in this block". I attached a minimal go project how to reproduce this issue. The structure of the project is like below:

[image]

`protos/myMessages/Folder0/MyMessage0.proto`

```
syntax = "proto2";

package myMessages.Folder0;

option go_package = "myMessages/Folder0";

message Message0 {
    optional uint32 payload = 1;
}
```

`protos/myMessages/Folder1/MyMessage1.proto`

```
syntax = "proto2";

package myMessages.Folder1;

option go_package = "myMessages/Folder1";

message Message0 {
    optional uint32 payload = 1;
}
```

`protos/myMessages/helloworld.proto`

```
syntax = "proto2";

package myMessages;

option go_package = "./;gen";

import "myMessages/Folder0/MyMessage0.proto";
import "myMessages/Folder1/MyMessage1.proto";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello1 (myMessages.Folder0.Message0) returns (myMessages.Folder0.Message0) {}
  rpc SayHello2 (myMessages.Folder1.Message0) returns (myMessages.Folder1.Message0) {}
}
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    
    pb0 "main/build/myMessages/Folder0"
    pb1 "main/build/myMessages/Folder1"
    pb "main/build"
)

var (
    port = flag.Int("port", 50051, "The server port")
)

// server is used to implement helloworld.GreeterServer.
type server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedGreeterServer
}

func (s *server) SayHello1(ctx context.Context, in *pb0.Message0) (*pb0.Message0, error) {
    return &pb0.Message0{}, nil
}

func (s *server) SayHello2(ctx context.Context, in *pb1.Message0) (*pb1.Message0, error) {
    return &pb1.Message0{}, nil
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    log.Printf("server listening at %v", lis.Addr())
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

`Makefile`

```
all: build protos

protos:
    protoc -Iprotos --go_out=build protos/myMessages/Folder0/MyMessage0.proto
    protoc -Iprotos --go_out=build protos/myMessages/Folder1/MyMessage1.proto
    protoc -Iprotos --go_out=build --go-grpc_out=build protos/helloworld.proto
    go build -o build/server main.go

build:
    mkdir -p build
```

After I run the `make` command, I get the error below:

```
mkdir -p build
protoc -Iprotos --go_out=build protos/myMessages/Folder0/MyMessage0.proto
protoc -Iprotos --go_out=build protos/myMessages/Folder1/MyMessage1.proto
protoc -Iprotos --go_out=build --go-grpc_out=build protos/helloworld.proto
go build -o build/server main.go
build/helloworld.pb.go:12:2: package myMessages/Folder0 is not in GOROOT (/home/andrei/env/gosdk/go1.17.2/src/myMessages/Folder0)
build/helloworld.pb.go:13:2: package myMessages/Folder1 is not in GOROOT (/home/andrei/env/gosdk/go1.17.2/src/myMessages/Folder1)
make: *** [Makefile:21: protos] Error 1
```

The generated `build/helloworld.pb.go` and `build/helloworld_grpc.pb.go` files have the following imports:

```
import (
    Folder0 "myMessages/Folder0"
    Folder1 "myMessages/Folder1"
)
```

But if I change these to the following then it works:

```
import (
    Folder0 "main/build/myMessages/Folder0"
    Folder1 "main/build/myMessages/Folder1"
)
```

What's the correct way to organise this code to avoid manually adding the `main/build` prefix to the imports in the generated files?

Comment: Can you share a bit more about your use case? It looks like there might be some copying errors the way you've renamed things (ex. `myMessages.Folder1.MyMessage1` isn't declared anywhere). I'd also suggest following more standardized package naming and file organization conventions. I find these rules helpful: https://docs.buf.build/best-practices/style-guide#files-and-packages

Comment: @SpencerConnaughton I will add a few more details to this question to rephrase. Basically I have a single proto file for gRPC services and loads of proto files in subfolders for gRPC messages. Two or more messages may share the same name: e.g. MyMessage1 in folder 1 and MyMessage1 in folder 2. I'm taking care of this in the proto file of gRPC by adding the package name to differentiate between them.

Comment: @SpencerConnaughton minimal example that triggers the problem added.

Comment: If the problem is simply that you don't want the `main/build` prefix, could you simply use `--go_out=.` instead of having the generated files go to the `build` folder?

Comment: I want the files to be generated in the `build` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

##### 1. Get your module name from `go.mod`. In this instance, I'll assume it's `hello-world`

```
module hello-world
...
```

##### 2. Configure the protos to build as subpackages of your module

`protos/myMessages/Folder0/MyMessage0.proto`

```
...
option go_package = "hello-world/myMessages/Folder0";
...
```

`protos/myMessages/Folder1/MyMessage1.proto`

```
...
option go_package = "hello-world/myMessages/Folder1";
...
```

`protos/myMessages/helloworld.proto`

```
...
option go_package = "hello-world/myMessages";
...
```

##### 3. Generate the proto code in your project directory using `source_relative` paths

```bash
protoc -Iprotos --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative protos/myMessages/Folder0/MyMessage0.proto
protoc -Iprotos --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative protos/myMessages/Folder1/MyMessage1.proto
protoc -Iprotos --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. protos/myMessages/helloworld.proto
```

You could also configure these and the `go_package` paths to use the `build` directory: use `--go_out=build` in this step, and change the go package paths in the previous and following steps to `"hello-world/build/myMessages/<something>"`.

However, I think `build` is better for build products (not generated code), and it isn't how they do it in the official example code: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial

##### 4. Import the `myMessages` submodules as necessary

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    ...

    pb "hello-world/myMessages"
    pb0 "hello-world/myMessages/Folder0"
    pb1 "hello-world/myMessages/Folder1"
)
...
```

---

I also suggest using `proto3` instead of `proto2` per: https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/proto3

> To simplify developer experience and improve runtime efficiency, gRPC APIs **should** use Protocol Buffers version 3 (proto3) for API definition.

I also suggest using [buf](https://github.com/bufbuild/buf) tools and/or building with [bazel](https://bazel.build/) instead of calling `protoc` directly to avoid chasing these problems around in the future.